# Let $F$ be a field with $4$ elements. Show $1+\alpha+\alpha^2 = 0$ for $\alpha \in F$ and $X^2 + \alpha$ is reducible in $F[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

Let $F$ be a field with $4$ elements and let $\alpha \in F$ be an element $\neq 0, 1$.

a) Show that $F = \{0,1,\alpha, \alpha^2\}$ and $1 + \alpha + \alpha^2 = 0$:

I know that $F^* = F - \{0\}$ is a group with operation $(\cdot)$, so $(F^*, \cdot)$ is a group of order $3$ with identity element $1$.

Since the order of every element in $F^*$ must divide $3$ we have $\langle \alpha \rangle = \{\alpha, \alpha^2, 1\}$ is the subgroup of $F^*$ generated by $\alpha$, so $\langle \alpha \rangle = F^*$ and $F = F^* \cup\{0\} = \{0, 1,\alpha, \alpha^2\}$.

However I don't know how to show $1 + \alpha + \alpha^2 = 0$. Thus I'm sure I should use the identity $\alpha^3 = 1$.

b) Also I must show $X^2 + \alpha$ is reducible and $X^2 + X + \alpha$ is irreducible in $F[X]$, but this amounts to show that one has a root and the other not (this I've proved).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

1. If you know that $\alpha^3=1$ and $\alpha\neq1$, then
   $$0=1-1=\alpha^3-1=(\alpha-1)(\alpha^2+\alpha+1).$$ Which of those factors can make the product zero?
2. If $\alpha^3=1$, then $\alpha^4=\alpha$. Therefore
   $$x^2+\alpha=x^2-\alpha=x^2-\alpha^4=x^2-(\alpha^2)^2.$$ Can you see that this is reducible? For part b) see e.g. [my earlier answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/627935/11619).

Comment: Thanks Jyrki. We know $(\alpha -1) \neq 0$ so $\alpha^2 + \alpha + 1$ must be zero.

Comment: Correct, Nicolas! Well done.

Comment: Jyrki, may I ask you: Suppose we have $\alpha, \lambda \in R$, where $R$ is a commutative ring. Also $\alpha, \lambda \neq 0,1$. Suppose $\lambda \cdot \alpha = \alpha$ - Is this possible with the assumption $\lambda \neq 1$ ? If $R$ is a domain then $\lambda \cdot \alpha = \alpha \Rightarrow \alpha \cdot (\lambda - 1) = 0$ a contradiction, since $\lambda \neq 1 \land \alpha \neq 0$. However what if $R$ is not a domain, but a general ring ?

Comment: @Nicolas: In the ring $\Bbb{Z}_4$ we have $3\cdot2=2$.

Comment: Ohh so in general we cannot say $\lambda \alpha = \alpha $, where $\lambda \neq 1$ implies $\alpha = 0$. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

If you multiply $1+\alpha+\alpha^2$ with $\alpha$ you get $\alpha+\alpha^2+1$, i.e. the same number. Which number remains unchanged when multiplied with a number $\ne 1$?

b) In th elight of the previous, you want an $x\in F$ such that $x^2+\alpha=0$, i.e. $x^2=1+\alpha^2$. Guess what is $(1+\alpha)^2$? Alternatively: what is the square of $\alpha^2$ by your cyclic group argument?

For $X^2+X+\alpha$ it suffices to show that plugging in any of the four values results in an expression that is *definitely* nonzero.

Comment: Thanks! - I know $0$ does, but then I must show that no other element does not equal the same element when multiplied by an element $\neq 1$.